# XCode 4.2 click on button switch to another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In Xcode 4.2, I know that one can use the storyboard segue to have a push of a button to go to another view.

But say i want to storyboard, but not using segue push, instead code my own button to display another view, how to do it?
Must i include a navigation controller?

EDIT: added source codes

AppDelegate.h

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  Sandbox1
//
//  Created on 6/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Sandbox1
//
//  Created on 6/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize navController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary     *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone"     bundle:nil];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window addSubview:[navController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Sandbox1
//
//  Created on 6/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CreateViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    CreateViewController *createViewController;
}

- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Sandbox1
//
//  Created on 6/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender{
    if(!createViewController){
        createViewController = [[CreateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:createViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

CreateViewController.h

```
//
//  CreateViewController.h
//  Sandbox1
//
//  Created bon 6/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CreateViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

CreateViewController.m

```
//
//  CreateViewController.m
//  Sandbox1
//
//

#import "CreateViewController.h"

@implementation CreateViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: This is not a code dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the button is in `FirstViewController`. If it is then implement -`(IBAction)clickButton` and write code and connect it to your bottom in Interface Builder(If you use Interface Builder) . write createViewController object and `#import <CreateViewController.h>` in FirstViewController.h and you should use `UINavigationController`.

In `FirstViewController.h`,

```
#import "CreateViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{

    CreateViewController *createViewController;
}
-(IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

In `FirstViewController.m`, you just add below method

```
 -(IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender{

if (!createViewController) {
                createViewController = [[CreateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateViewController" bundle:nil];

            }

            UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
            [backBarButtonItem release];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:createViewController animated:YES];
}
```

and in `AppDelegate.h`,

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navControl;
@end
```

In `AppDelegate.m,`

```
@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize navControl;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
[self.window addSubview:[navControl view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi Prasad, thx for the help. I followed your codes and I run the app on simulator, I got a error like below...
2012-06-29 15:57:56.444 Sandbox1[2057:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/starnewmedia/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/1300A426-503C-4E7D-A3DD-8385FCDCDFF0/Sandbox1.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController_iPhone''
what did I missed out?

Comment: Did you connect the button to clickButton method in .xib file?

Comment: Well, I have ctrl and left-click and drag the button from the storyboard (not xib) into the - (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender; at ViewController.h file. Still the same, I got black screen, then i got SIGABRT error and the error I mentioned above.

Comment: I edited my post, and included the source codes, I still not sure what is wrong. Is it something that I need to add to my ViewController at the MainStoryboard.storyboard? Like adding this "ViewController_iPhone" to somewhere in the storyboard??

Comment: Actually you don't have ViewController_iPhone.xib file. You replace '[[ViewController alloc] init;'  instead of '[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone"     bundle:nil];'. Try like this.

Comment: Ok, at AppDelegate.h I changed to self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init]; and ViewController.h I changed to createViewController = [[CreateViewController alloc] init]; I run the simulator again, now I got one blue bar above, and all black just after the blue bar. Somehow, the view didn't get load.

Comment: Yes, I run it, no more error, no SIGABRT error. I can see my iPhone simulator. However, I don't see my view on the iPhone simulator screen. I just see a blue bar just on the top of the screen, and the rest of the screen is black color.

Comment: The code is correct. But error is some where. Can you send your code to me? I shall check it.

Comment: could I get your email so that I can send the zipped up codes to you. or you can drop me an email to mssurface@yahoo.com